# Wither for Python?

Tags: python, lombok, boilerplate

In Java's Lombok there is a functionality called `wither`that clones an existing instance and changes just one attribute of it ([wither](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither)).

Is there anything comparable in Python?

(Python projects similar to Lombok seem to be the following, but they do not have this functionality:

1. https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs
2. https://pysynthetic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
3. https://github.com/IgniparousTempest/puffadder/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python library [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html) provides this functionality with [attr.evolve](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=evolve#attr.evolve)

Here's an example copied from the docs:

```
>>> @attr.s
... class C(object):
...     x = attr.ib()
...     y = attr.ib()
>>> i1 = C(1, 2)
>>> i1
C(x=1, y=2)
>>> i2 = attr.evolve(i1, y=3)
>>> i2
C(x=1, y=3)
>>> i1 == i2  # False
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `copy.copy`

```
import copy

my_copy = copy.copy(my_obj)
my_copy.my_attribute = my_value
```

Note that this performs a shallow copy, i.e. all references to other objects (like lists) will point to the same object. If you need a "deep" copy, use `copy.deepcopy(my_obj)` instead.

This works with most, but not all objects.